# Input time only minutes and seconds

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure out how to have a `<input type="time">` that only displays minutes and seconds, does anyone know how this can be done. I have tried time pickers but they don't seem to work.

Can anyone help thanks?

Comment: Could you add the code you are trying to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on your local system time settings, make 24 hours then it will show you 24 hours time.

But you can use **time-picker** libraries: https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js

An example:

```js
var timepicker = new TimePicker('time', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
  
  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know if there is a way to have minutes and seconds only

Comment: It`s possible, see docs of this library